# Bulk update products to include new websites

Tags: product, multistore, products-management

A client has 20000+ products with 7 websites. They used to have 4 websites and most products are associated to 4 websites. What is the best & quickest way to iterate through the products and update the products to include the new websites.

I have the following code however it is far too slow:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('like' => '02%'));
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    echo $product->getSku();
    $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
    try {
        $product->save();
        echo " - saved.";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo ' - '.$e->getMessage();
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

I were thinking of using the iterator walk method however I understand that the store/website isn't exactly an attribute so it can't be easily updated on its own.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Step 1**
Build an array with your new website ids.

```
$websiteIds = array(5,6,7);
```

**Step 2**
Now get all the product ids.

```
$productIds= Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->getAllIds();
```

**Step 3**
Assign all the products to the new websites:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->addProducts($websiteIds, $productIds);
```

**Step 4**
Feel good about yourself.

Comment: Thank you Marius. Perfect answer. (I would vote up but I can't yet)

Comment: step 5 create a gist: https://gist.github.com/mauricioprado00/2b730532689d28dcdb2b.  you can do "php -f shell/product-website.php -- --products all --websites all" or specify websites/products ids.

Comment: wow... that is an amazingly perfect efficient solution. Even I was going to loop around all those many products to update them. I want to know how to learn such concepts about Magento.

Comment: In typical Marius fashion, worked like a charm!

Comment: The products do not seem to appear in the flat catalog and are not visible on the frontend. When using the - save() method the products do appear. Does anyone know why Marius' method gives this problem? M1.9, 4 websites, 15k products, flat catalog

Comment: @TomLank.because you need to rebuild the indexes when you are done.

Comment: I've apply you solution the website id set but the product not display on particular website. I've also done re-index & remove cache.

Comment: Is there a maximum to $productIds? Testing now with 400+ values and receiving `Uncaught Mage_Core_Exception: An error occurred while adding products to websites`

Comment: I don't think there is a limit. This is the general error message. You can try to debug in the  class ` Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Website::addProducts`. ON the `catch` branch, pass as a message to the new extension that is being thrown `$e->getMessage()` which is the message from exception itself.

Comment: If you care to bet on it, my money is on "you send a product id that is not in catalog_product_entity table and it fails when inserting into the `catalog_product_website` table because of a foreign key check". or you send the same id twice.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to add the products that are assigned to *all* 4 previously existing websites, use this:

```
$oldWebsiteIds = [2, 3, 4, 5];
$newWebsiteIds = [6, 7, 8]

/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$productCollection->addWebsiteFilter($oldWebsiteIds );
// only filter products present in ALL of the websites
$productCollection->getSelect()
    ->having('COUNT(website_id) = ?', count($oldWebsiteIds))
    ->distinct(false)
    ->group('e.entity_id');
$productIds = $productCollection->getAllIds();

Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->addProducts($newWebsiteIds, $productIds);
```

See also: 
[Filter products by website using AND](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/74336/243)

This can be a Magento setup script or a throwaway PHP script (in this case add `include 'app/Mage.php';` at the top and remove it from the server after usage)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution if your laziness goes to the point of not wanting to create any PHP files:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO catalog_product_website
SELECT entity_id, {website_id} FROM catalog_product_entity
```

Worked for me.

Comment: +1 from me. But its not generate the product URL's. Magento Version 2.3.5 so reindex will not work. So have you an idea about URL.

Comment: @H_Parekh why not making a big manual reindex in command line?

Comment: ,Thanks for the reply. I have reindex but in Magento 2 there is no reindex for URL's.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Get all website Ids/make array of website Ids**

```
$websiteIds = Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_collection')->getAllIds();
```

**Step 2: Get all product Ids**

```
$productIds= Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->getAllIds();
```

**Step 3: Add website ids to all product**

```
$actionModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');
$actionModel->updateWebsites($productIds, $websiteIds, 'add');
```

**Note:** If you want to remove the website from product. use **remove** instead **add** word

```
$actionModel->updateWebsites($productIds, $websiteIds, 'remove');
```

Comment: is this faster? Or how is it different from Marius solution?