# Filter products by website using AND

Tags: multistore, collection, product-collection, collection-filtering, websites

In a multistore setup, I need to find products that are assigned to website A **and** website B.

The product collection has a `addWebsiteFilter()` method but unfortunately it doesn't serve this purpose, as can be seen in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::_productLimitationJoinWebsite()`, where the filter gets applied:

```
        $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
            ->quoteInto('product_website.website_id IN(?)', $filters['website_ids']);
```

The query will match for all products that are assigned to **any** of the given websites. What is the best way to build a query for products that are present in multiple websites?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There it is. Given `$websiteIds` is an array of website ids:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$productCollection->addWebsiteFilter($websiteIds);
$productCollection->getSelect()
    ->having('COUNT(website_id) = ?', count($websiteIds))
    ->distinct(false)
    ->group('e.entity_id');
```

I removed `DISTINCT` and grouped by product instead to be able to `COUNT` the number of joined websites. If it is equal to the total number of filtered websites, the product is assigned to all of them.

Comment: How to get PRODUCT collection which are assigned to ONLY ONE STORE , by passing store id to ->addStoreFilter();

Comment: @SheshgiriAnvekar This is a different question, please use the "Ask Question" button

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222049/filter-products-by-store-id-in-magento-1