# Bulk update products to include new websites in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, multistore, websites

I saw [This link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16293/bulk-update-products-to-include-new-websites) and I want to do the same thing in magento 2.
I want to associate all products to some list of websites.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution there is a method in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` named `updateWebsites($productIds, $websiteIds, 'add');`