# Displaying same categories and products on all website

Tags: magento-1.9, database, category-products

I want to create multiple Magento website on same domain for different countries, something like:

- www.domain.com/us for the U.S.
- www.domain.com/uk for the U.K.
- www.domain.com/de for Germany

etc.

Products are going to be same on all websites, the things that will differ are Language, product description & currency. How can I display same products & categories across all websites? I tried creating multiple sites & kept the default category as default, but neither products, nor categories are appearing on any website other than the Main website.

Answer (score 0):

You can bulk edit all the products and mark them to appear on all the websites.
You can do that from the product admin list, select all and select the action "update attributes" from the top right corner.
If you have a lot of products that will most probably time out.
In this case, you can take a "code" approach and do it like this:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16295/146